# What markdown is this?

Tags: markdown

What markdown is this? And how do I decode/parse it into HTML?

> Fraym is a geospatial data company that uses proprietary machine learning algorithms to deliver precise, local-level information about people in Africa, Asia, and Latin America. The company helps fast-growing companies, government agencies, and development organizations succeed in places where data has been traditionally hard to access. Fraym’s granular data adds an entirely new dimension to strategic and operational planning discussions, and answers questions like, ‘where are my target populations?’, ‘where is the greatest need for program intervention’, and ‘what services are they interested in?’. \n\nWe are looking for a mid-level full-stack Software Engineer with a knack for quality design and usability to join our Product Delivery team. \n\n\n\n\n\n\nYou will perform a range of responsibilities including the following:\n\n\n\n\n* Evaluate internal and client priorities to develop software-based solutions;\n\n* Communicate with users and stakeholders to understand evolving needs and customer’s concerns;\n\n* Translate complex analysis and data into relatable and actionable software and user interfaces;\n\n* Contribute to building the roadmap of the product: GitHub issue creation, epic/sprint evaluation, backlog grooming, etc.;\n\n* Write maintainable code and offer PR reviews;\n\n* Write unit and smoke tests for all portions of our applications;\n\n* Monitor and improve on internal systems and practices related to code workflow and peer review;\n\n* Create markdown documents to help new engineers and developers get started with our tools and projects;\n\n* Automate software deployment process;\n\n* Collaborate cross-functionally with the Data and Go-to-Market teams to understand customer needs.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nYou are expected to have the following qualifications and skills:\n\n\n* Required Qualifications\n\n\n\n* Experience working in a remote setting, or with a remote team and across multiple time zones;\n\n* Fast learner, i.e.: we routinely pick up new languages or leverage frameworks;\n\n* Ability to collaborate with external consultants;\n\n* At least 5 years of experience building web-based software products;\n\n* Self-motivated and independent;\n\n* Persistent and with desire to solve both technical problems and learn multi-faceted business concepts;\n\n* Critical understanding of data and geospatial concepts;\n\n* Working experience with mainstream frameworks such as Ruby on Rails, Django or WordPress;\n\n* Past experience building UIs based on Angular 4 (or higher) or React.\n\n* Commitment to diversity, equity, and inclusion\n\n\n\n* Preferred Qualifications\n\n\n\n* Experience with CSS frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation;\n\n* Experience working with GIS technologies, e.g.: Mapbox GL JS, Carto, PostGIS, etc.;\n\n* Experience and interest in working on African and other emerging markets;\n\n* Experience working with data and large databases;\n\n* Experience working with AWS;\n\n* Experience working in or with young, early-stage companies.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nBenefits\n\n\n\n\n* Competitive compensation package, including performance bonus;\n\n* Medical, dental, vision coverage, and more;\n\n* Opportunities for significant career advancement in a fast-growing, young company;\n\n* Flexible work environment.\n\n* Commitment to work-life balance\n\n* Opportunities for career advancement and professional development in a fast-growing company\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nFraym recruits, employs, trains, compensates and promotes regardless of race, color, religion, gender, gender identity or expression, sexual orientation, national origin, genetics, disability, age, family status, veteran status, and other protected status as required by applicable law

Comment: This is not markdown at all, it's plain text. Replace all of the `\n`s with new lines and it's done.

Comment: [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is a specific language with a few well-known variants. It's not a general term. Maybe you want to know what [mark_up_ language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace \n symbols to 'new line' as \n is not MD option. You can do it in VS Code or Notepad++ for example - `Ctrl + H`, select `Use Regular expression`, search `\\n`, Replace - `\n`, `Replace All`.

[image]

Then use any tool from google 'markdown to html' (for example https://markdowntohtml.com/).

Here is your result

```html
<p>Fraym is a geospatial data company that uses proprietary machine learning algorithms to deliver precise, local-level information about people in Africa, Asia, and Latin America. The company helps fast-growing companies, government agencies, and development organizations succeed in places where data has been traditionally hard to access. Fraym’s granular data adds an entirely new dimension to strategic and operational planning discussions, and answers questions like, ‘where are my target populations?’, ‘where is the greatest need for program intervention’, and ‘what services are they interested in?’. </p>
<p>We are looking for a mid-level full-stack Software Engineer with a knack for quality design and usability to join our Product Delivery team. </p>
<p>You will perform a range of responsibilities including the following:</p>
<ul>
<li><p>Evaluate internal and client priorities to develop software-based solutions;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Communicate with users and stakeholders to understand evolving needs and customer’s concerns;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Translate complex analysis and data into relatable and actionable software and user interfaces;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Contribute to building the roadmap of the product: GitHub issue creation, epic/sprint evaluation, backlog grooming, etc.;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Write maintainable code and offer PR reviews;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Write unit and smoke tests for all portions of our applications;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Monitor and improve on internal systems and practices related to code workflow and peer review;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Create markdown documents to help new engineers and developers get started with our tools and projects;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Automate software deployment process;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Collaborate cross-functionally with the Data and Go-to-Market teams to understand customer needs.</p>
</li>
</ul>
<p>You are expected to have the following qualifications and skills:</p>
<ul>
<li>Required Qualifications</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><p>Experience working in a remote setting, or with a remote team and across multiple time zones;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Fast learner, i.e.: we routinely pick up new languages or leverage frameworks;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Ability to collaborate with external consultants;</p>
</li>
<li><p>At least 5 years of experience building web-based software products;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Self-motivated and independent;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Persistent and with desire to solve both technical problems and learn multi-faceted business concepts;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Critical understanding of data and geospatial concepts;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Working experience with mainstream frameworks such as Ruby on Rails, Django or WordPress;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Past experience building UIs based on Angular 4 (or higher) or React.</p>
</li>
<li><p>Commitment to diversity, equity, and inclusion</p>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Preferred Qualifications</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><p>Experience with CSS frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Experience working with GIS technologies, e.g.: Mapbox GL JS, Carto, PostGIS, etc.;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Experience and interest in working on African and other emerging markets;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Experience working with data and large databases;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Experience working with AWS;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Experience working in or with young, early-stage companies.</p>
</li>
</ul>
<p>Benefits</p>
<ul>
<li><p>Competitive compensation package, including performance bonus;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Medical, dental, vision coverage, and more;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Opportunities for significant career advancement in a fast-growing, young company;</p>
</li>
<li><p>Flexible work environment.</p>
</li>
<li><p>Commitment to work-life balance</p>
</li>
<li><p>Opportunities for career advancement and professional development in a fast-growing company</p>
</li>
</ul>
<p>Fraym recruits, employs, trains, compensates and promotes regardless of race, color, religion, gender, gender identity or expression, sexual orientation, national origin, genetics, disability, age, family status, veteran status, and other protected status as required by applicable law</p>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. 

Now I just need to write that regular expression and add a php library to do this for the object that contains this.

Thank you! <3